# Jquery Check if Array contains empty entry

Tags: jquery, arrays

I have an array : `var list = ["",""];`that will be filled with strings.

Before I let the user do something, I would like to make sure the array doesn't contain anymore empty entry.

I made a special function that I would like to work like that:

```
function checkEmptryEntry(array_name)
{
   if(arrayContainsEmptyEntry(array_name))
   {
      return "bad";
   }

   else
   {
      return "good";
   }
}
```

How could I do that ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I check if an array includes an object in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/237104/how-do-i-check-if-an-array-includes-an-object-in-javascript)

Comment: What have you tried so far? Iterate through the array and check for at least one empty string, and please return a boolean.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you have used jquery, you can use `inArray`:

```
return (!jQuery.inArray("", array_name) ? "good" : "bad");
```

Using native javascript, You can use `indexOf` to find first position of empty string. if it return -1, then array have no empty string:

```
return (array_name.indexOf("") == -1 ? "good" : "bad" ) ;
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for ! Thanks Milind !